# Android WebView Request header too large exception

Tags: android, http-headers, android-webview

When loading some pages in webview, after few times I receive this exception **Request Header Or Session Cookie Too Large** displayed in WebView.

The way URL is loaded in WebView:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.idWebView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Accept-Language", getLanguage());
webView.loadUrl(url, headers);
```

Just to be clear, this happens even without **headers.put("Accept-Language", getLanguage());**

I am not sure if this should be fixed on Android or on the server side.
Did anyone run in to the similar problem on Android WebViews?

This is the console log for this exception:

> request header: {X-Requested-With=ch.denner.inhouse, Cookie=store=de; ls_mage-translation-storage=%7B%7D; ss_94680522_mage-translation-storage=%7B%7D; mage-translation-storage=%7B%7D; ss_94680522_mage-translation-file-version=%7B%7D; mage-translation-file-version=%7B%7D; ls_mage-translation-file-version=%7B%22version%22%3A%224a03928408a7b94f82c301d4277eff8aee6c47f7%22%7D; ss_94680522_mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; ss_94680522_mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; ls_mage-cache-timeout=%222018-04-11T08%3A55%3A05.513Z%22; ls_recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; ss_94680522_recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; ls_recently_viewed_product_previous=%7B%7D; ss_94680522_recently_viewed_product_previous=%7B%7D; ls_recently_compared_product=%7B%7D; ss_94680522_recently_compared_product=%7B%7D; ls_recently_compared_product_previous=%7B%7D; ss_94680522_recently_compared_product_previous=%7B%7D; ls_product_data_storage=%7B%7D; ss_94680522_product_data_storage=%7B%7D; ss_13756572_mage-translation-storage=%7B%7D; ss_13756572_mage-translation-file-version=%7B%7D; ss_13756572_mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; ss_13756572_mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; ss_13756572_recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; ss_13756572_recently_viewed_product_previous=%7B%7D; ss_13756572_recently_compared_product=%7B%7D; ss_13756572_recently_compared_product_previous=%7B%7D; ss_13756572_product_data_storage=%7B%7D; ss_69184443_mage-translation-storage=%7B%7D; ss_69184443_mage-translation-file-version=%7B%7D; ss_69184443_mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; ss_69184443_mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; ss_69184443_recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; ss_69184443_recently_viewed_product_previous=%7B%7D; ss_69184443_recently_compared_product=%7B%7D; ss_69184443_recently_compared_product_previous=%7B%7D; ss_69184443_product_data_storage=%7B%7D; ss_11203415_mage-translation-storage=%7B%7D; ss_11203415_mage-translation-file-version=%7B%7D; ss_11203415_mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; ss_11203415_mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; ss_11203415_recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; ss_11203415_recently_viewed_product_previous=%7B%7D; ss_11203415_recently_compared_product=%7B%7D; ss_11203415_recently_compared_product_previous=%7B%7D; ss_11203415_product_data_storage=%7B%7D; ss_51744436_mage-translation-storage=%7B%7D; ss_51744436_mage-translation-file-version=%7B%7D; ss_51744436_mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; ss_51744436_mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; ss_51744436_recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; ss_51744436_recently_viewed_product_previous=%7B%7D; ss_51744436_recently_compared_product=%7B%7D; ss_51744436_recently_compared_product_previous=%7B%7D; ss_51744436_product_data_storage=%7B%7D; ss_98351072_mage-translation-storage=%7B%7D; ss_98351072_mage-translation-file-version=%7B%7D; ss_98351072_mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; ss_98351072_mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; ls_private_content_version=a34cb889d50dcc9485592bb349ad209b; ls_mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; ss_98351072_recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; ss_98351072_recently_viewed_product_previous=%7B%7D; ss_98351072_recently_compared_product=%7B%7D; ss_98351072_recently_compared_product_previous=%7B%7D; ss_98351072_product_data_storage=%7B%7D; ls_mage-cache-storage=%7B%22cart%22%3A%7B%22summary_count%22%3A0%2C%22subtotalAmount%22%3Anull%2C%22subtotal%22%3A%22%3Cspan%20class%3D%5C%22price%5C%22%3EFr.%20%C2%A00.00%3C%2Fspan%3E%22%2C%22possible_onepage_checkout%22%3Atrue%2C%22items%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22extra_actions%22%3A%22%22%2C%22isGuestCheckoutAllowed%22%3Atrue%2C%22website_id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22subtotal_incl_tax%22%3A%22%3Cspan%20class%3D%5C%22price%5C%22%3EFr.%20%C2%A00.00%3C%2Fspan%3E%22%2C%22subtotal_excl_tax%22%3A%22%3Cspan%20class%3D%5C%22price%5C%22%3EFr.%20%C2%A00.00%3C%2Fspan%3E%22%2C%22denner_total_bottles%22%3A0%2C%22denner_subtotal_catalog_discount%22%3A0%2C%22data_id%22%3A1523434856%7D%2C%22customweb_external_checkout_widgets%22%3A%7B%22html%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22data_id%22%3A1523434855%7D%2C%22customer%22%3A%7B%22data_id%22%3A1523434855%7D%2C%

Comment: Are you using CookieManager to set cookie ? If yes , can you share the same code as well !

Comment: Hi @ShubhamSrivastava,

no, i am not using any CookieManager on Android, all code used for loading URL is inside this post

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava any feedback? When loading any other URL, I am not getting similar errors, just on this specific web site that client provided us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

I added the following code to my custom WebView (you can add it anywhere you want).

```
private void clearCookies() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
        CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
        return;
    }

    CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getContext());
    cookieSyncManager.startSync();
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
    cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
    cookieSyncManager.stopSync();
    cookieSyncManager.sync();
}
```

So, before loading any URL, I just call **clearCookies()**